# Spring Cloud config authentication with AWS Code Commit

Tags: java, git, spring-cloud-config, aws-codecommit

I'm novice to use spring cloud config server, so is first time for me and i hope i can receive help, thanks in advance for this.
What i can try to do is to configure Spring cloud Configuration Server as central server for configurations among all Microservices. 
We are using AWS CodeCommit as SCM repository.
The problem is that i receive always the same error once i try to inve an existing file on AWS CC. 
I suppose is a problem of authentication, but i'm not sure
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnbVP.png)
This is the bootstrap configuration on Spring CSC

```
server.port=9090
management.security.enabled=false
logging.level.org.springframework.web: TRACE
spring.application.name=config-service
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri: https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/ServiceLayer
```

This is the file in my SCM repository that i'm trying to call:

```
configuration:  
  projectName: ms-login
server:  
  port: 8000
message:  
  greeting: Hello from the configuration
```

I've make a several try:

1. Placed the AWS GIT Credential (NOT the AWS Secret key) in bootstrap properties, but without result. Example:

   spring.cloud.config.server.git.username: sergio.greco-at-682088819034
   spring.cloud.config.server.git.password: xxxxxxx
2. Placed the AWS Secret Key \ Identity ID as java parameter once start, as follow:

   -Daws.accessKeyId=xxxxxxxxYNOA -Daws.secretKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3. Set environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \ AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Forget to put in question the invocation uri that i'm using:
http://localhost:9090/ms-login/default/developer
where:
> ms-login is the projectname value
> default is the profile
> developer is label (branch in git)

Answer (score 0):

You need has the AWS SDK in the classpath. 
Relevant documentation on this: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.3.1.RELEASE/

Search for “Authentication with AWS CodeCommit”.

Note: The aws-java-sdk-core jar is an optional dependency. If the aws-java-sdk-core jar is not on your classpath, then the AWS Code Commit credential provider will not be created regardless of the git server URI.